# urlopen() throwing error in python 3.3

Tags: python-3.x, unicode, ascii, urlopen

```
from urllib.request import urlopen

def ShowResponse(param):
    uri = str("mysite.com/?param="+param+"&submit=submit")
    print(urlopen(uri).read())

file = open("myfile.txt","r")
if file.mode == "r":
    filelines = file.readlines()
    for line in filelines:
        line = line.strip()
        ShowResponse(line)
```

this is my python code but when i run this it causes an error `"UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 47-49: ordinal not in range(128)`"
i dont know how to fix this. im new to python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume that the stack trace shows that line 4 (`uri = str(...`) is throwing the given error and `myfile.txt` contains UTF-8 characters.

The error is because you're trying to convert a Unicode object (decoded from assumed UTF-8) to an ASCII string object. ASCII simply can not represent your character.

URIs (including the Query String) must encode non-ASCII chars as percent-encoded UTF-8 bytes. Example:

> € (EURO SIGN) is encoded in UTF-8 is:
>
> > 0xE2 0x82 0xAC
>
> Percent-encoded, it's:
>
> > %E2%82%AC

Therefore, your code needs to re-encode your parameter to UTF-8 then percent-encode it:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen, quote


def ShowResponse(param):
    param_utf8 = param.encode("utf-8")
    param_perc_encoded = quote(param_utf8)

    # or uri = str("mysite.com/?param="+param_perc_encoded+"&submit=submit")
    uri = str("mysite.com/?param={0}&submit=submit".format(param_perc_encoded) )
    print(urlopen(uri).read())
```

You'll also see I've changed your `uri =` definition slightly to use String.format() (https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax), which I find easier to create complex strings rather than doing string concatenation with +. In this example, `{0}` is replaced with the first argument to `.format()`.